# Is there a better way to log than writing logger.info() after every line using Nlog in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, logging

I am making a test with Selenium and several libraries in C#. 
In Java, there was WebDriver Event listener which could build a class with relevant event listeners.

I am looking for a solution where I don't have to write log.info() and log.error() after every line/step.

What is the best practice in c#? Is it possible to somehow create a generic event listener connected to a logger?

If my question is to vague, I am sorry. I tried to find the answer online. In that case, please guide me to the right direction. 
Thanks!

Comment: I tried doing something similar [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/119278/method-parameter-tracer)

Answer (score 0):

`WebDriverEventListener` exists also in C#. You need the Selenium.Support Nuget package for that.